# Proper way to let airflow sensor continuous triggering?

Tags: airflow

Is it possible to let airflow sensor continuous triggering?  By continuous triggering what I mean is that for example the sensor will listen to a Kafka topic, and will trigger different DAGs depend on the received message, this will keep running possible forever.

Answer (score 0):

The sensor doesn't trigger the dag run, it's a part of the run, but it can block it by staying in running state (or up for rescheduling) waiting certain condition, then all the downstream tasks will stay waiting (None state).

To achieve what you want to do, you can create a sub class from [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html#airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun.TriggerDagRunOperator) to read the kafka topic then trigger runs in other dags based on your needs.

Or you can create a stream application outside Airflow, and use the [Airflow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html) to trigger the runs.

Comment: Do you mean implement a sub class from TriggerDagRunOperator where it wait in a loop for the incoming message, and continuous triggering DAG?

Comment: yes, that what I mean

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Deferable operators, you should be able to re-defer them after re-entering , untested pseudo code would be something like :

```py
def execute(self,context) -> Any:

    self.defer(AwaitMessageTrigger(), method="execute_complete")

def execute_complete(self,context,event):

    TriggerDagRunOperator(conf=event)
    self.defer(AwaitMessageTrigger(), method="execute_complete")
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern has been implemented as part of the provider package here.

https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-provider-kafka/blob/main/airflow_provider_kafka/operators/event_triggers_function.py

Example here

https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-provider-kafka/blob/main/example_dags/listener_dag_function.py